# scraping a dynamic table in vb.net using selenium

Tags: vb.net, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a dynamic table from this website ("https://www.coinglass.com/merge/BTC-USDT"), its the orderbook on the right hand side. my code does not return any thing in my listbox, any help would be appreciated.

```
 Dim options As New ChromeOptions()
    options.AddArgument("start-maximized")
    options.AddArgument("--headless") ' Add this line to hide the browser window
    Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
    driver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, options) ' Initialize the driver at the class level

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.coinglass.com/merge/BTC-USDT")

    While Not BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending
        Thread.Sleep(3000)

        Dim table As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("orderbook-trades"))

        Dim rows As ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement) = table.FindElements(By.TagName("div"))

        Dim data As New List(Of String())

        For i = 0 To rows.Count - 1 Step 3
            Dim price As String = rows(i).FindElement(By.ClassName("bybt-long-font")).Text
            Dim size As String = rows(i + 1).Text
            Dim time As String = rows(i + 2).FindElement(By.TagName("div")).Text

            data.Add(price & " " & size & " " & time)
        Next

        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, data)
    End While

    driver.Quit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a few issues:

1. Instead of using a sleep, just wait for there to be more than one row.
2. The first row you pull is the header row so it doesn't have `.FindElement(By.ClassName("bybt-long-font"))` and `.FindElement(By.TagName("div"))`. You need to skip the first row.
3. What you are calling `table` is actually a row.
4. What you are calling `rows` is actually cells.
5. The "bybt-long-font" class doesn't always exist. Sometimes it's "bybt-short-font". You can change the locator and get both.
6. Most times the third cell (Time) is actually empty so that should be expected.
7. You don't really need to loop through the cells since you are doing something different to each one. Just use the index.

I would update your code to

```
Dim rows As ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement)
Dim cells As ReadOnlyCollection(Of IWebElement)
Dim data As New List(Of String())
Dim price As String
Dim size As String
Dim time As String

While Not BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending
    rows = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("orderbook-trades"))
    ' wait until more than just the header row exists
    While rows.Count <= 1
        rows = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("orderbook-trades"))
    ' look at header row + 1
    cells = rows(1).FindElements(By.TagName("div"))

    price = cells(0).FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > span")).Text
    size = cells(1).Text
    time = cells(2).FindElement(By.TagName("div")).Text
    data.Add(price & " " & size & " " & time)
    Debug.Print(price & " " & size & " " & time)

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, data)
End While
```

---

Just be aware that this code will not return every row in that table. It might print the same one twice if nothing new has printed. It might skip a few if several new trades come in during the loop. You'd have to do a LOT more work to make it print every single trade.

Comment: hi and thanks for your reply, unfortunately your code did not work.  it did not print any rows at all.

Comment: I've added a `Debug.Print()` statement to my answer. Try that and see if anything prints.

Comment: thanks the reply, debug messages are blank.